# Top 10 Record And Writeline

Tags: asp-classic

How I can write new line array?. And How I can read top 10 records?

```
Dim arrFileLines()
i = 0
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\FSO\ScriptLog.txt", 1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
 Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
 arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine
 i = i + 1
Loop
objFile.Close
For l = Ubound(arrFileLines) to LBound(arrFileLines) Step -1
 Wscript.Echo arrFileLines(l)
Next
```

Thanks for Answers

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FileContents, arrFileLines
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\FSO\ScriptLog.txt", 1)
FileContents = objFile.ReadAll()
objFile.Close()
Set objFile = Nothing
arrFileLines = Split(FileContents, vbCrLf)

Dim i, j
For i = LBound(arrFileLines) To UBound(arrFileLines)
   Response.Write(arrFileLines(i))
   j = j + 1
   If (j > 10) Then
      Exit For
   End If
Next
```